# Sending an email to host 'smtp.gmail.com' is always erroring

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to programatically send an email and I keep getting the following error:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com'

This is the code I'm trying:

```
string sender = "example@gmail.com";
string password = "myPwd";
string host = "smtp.gmail.com";
int port = "587";
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
smtpServer.Host = host;
mail.From = new MailAddress(sender);
mail.To.Add(recipient);
mail.Subject = emailSubject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtpServer.Port = port;
smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sender, password);
smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

I am trying always but I don't understand what is going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you ping `smtp.gmail.com` from the `command prompt` ? Do you know what the command prompt, is?

Comment: `ping smtp.gmail.com` then output as **
Ping request could not find host smtp.gmail.com. Please check the name and try again.**

Comment: `smtp.live.com` != `smtp.gmail.com` ....

Comment: Do you use a proxy server? It sounds like you don't have direct DNS access

Comment: Agreed @MatthewSteeples - that's what I was trying to figure out, in baby steps. Can the domain name be resolved AND is accessible (in one check) :)

Comment: Due to firewall, it was blocking. we opened port, now it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

google changed it's security policy you need to change your account settings as described [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en-GB)